# Can you set an Active Directory username and password using Chrome capabilities?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ruby, chrome

I currently have tests in rspec/capybara that use Active Directory to automatically log users in. I would like to specify a different username/password within a Chrome profile in order to test different accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change URL with authentication to: http://user:password@www.yourserveradress.com . This will work in part of situations and will authenticate you to needed service.

Credit goes to the following blog post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247051/handling-windows-authentication-with-selenium-webdriver